# Android Facebook SDK 3 requesting new permissions return to login listener

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I writing an Android application using Facebook SDK 3 for Android.

The architecture of this SDK is soooo wrong, that i have a wired behavior coming by.

my flow is as follow:

1. The user login to the application with basic permissions.
2. When ever I need some other permissions, I'm checking if the user has already permitted them, and if not, I will show him the Facebook UI dialog for giving me this permissions.

As simple as it my sound, the login flow works great, but whenever I'm trying to permit more permissions, after the user accept those permission, my `StatucCallback` listener from the login flow is being called, instead of the new callback I'm giving as parameter on the `Session.getActiveSession()`.

This is my code for in my `FacebookManager` class:

```
/**
 * start a logging session to facebook
 * @param callback the callback listener
 */
public void startLoginSession(StatusCallback callback)
{
    //get the session
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    //open if needed
    if (session == null || session.isClosed() || !session.isOpened())
        Session.openActiveSession(mainActivity, true, callback);
    else
        callback.call(session, session.getState(), null);
}

/**
 * Start a new user events session. 
 * @param callback the callback listener for the session request
 */
public void startUserEventsSession(StatusCallback callback)
{
    //get the session
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    //open if needed
    String permission = mainActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_event_permission);
    if (session == null || session.isClosed() || !session.isOpened())
        Session.openActiveSession(mainActivity, true, callback);
    //if permission is already granted
    if (isPermissionGranted(session, permission))
        callback.call(session, session.getState(), null);
    //ask for new permission
    else
    {               
        NewPermissionsRequest request = createPermissionRequest(permission);            
        request.setCallback(callback);              
        session.requestNewReadPermissions(request);
    }
}
```

As you can see, both of them are receiving a `StatusCallback` and I'm passing different status `callbacks` to each of them.. and yet the callback after user's first permitting my application goes to same as the login...

BTW, if the permission is already granted - the call function is called in the right listener.

I have a suspicious that it has something to do with the `Activity.onActivityResults()` function that is called after the user is giving new permissions, but I did defined a new callback so...???

Comment: It's an unfortunate misnomer, but the StatusCallback should have been called a StatusListener since they follow the listener pattern rather than a Callback. As such, any previous callbacks added to the active session will be called whenever the session is updated.

Comment: I thought its something like that. Is there a way to clear the listeners before adding a new one? Or should i build a new session manually? And moreover, where did you find info about it?thier documantation is lack if information, and that an understatement...

Comment: There's a removeCallback method on the Session class.

Comment: yeah i found it. thanks, all finally works now.. but the frustration... ohhhh the frustration...